# How to sort multiple drop downs by ascending order in terms of their label text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, dropdown

I have two drop downs in a form and i want to sort the values by alphabetic order.so i tried to implement by jquery. Actually it is working in ascending order  but all drop down values are appearing in each drop downs which mean duplication occurring( first drop down values are appearing in second drop down and vice versa).

My code is

```js
$(function() {
  var select = $('select');
  select.html(select.find('option').sort(function(x, y) {
    return $(x).text() > $(y).text() ? 1 : -1;
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option selected>Choose a number</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
  </select>
 
   <select>
    <option selected>Choose a number</option>
    <option value="3">cxbcbcb</option>
    <option value="1">Obcbcbcne</option>
    <option value="0">Zbcbero</option>
    <option value="2">detygey</option>
    <option value="8">eyeyeyy</option>
  </select>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: why do you want to sort it using jquery. before building the select list itself you can sort/manipulate your data and append in select list?

Comment: This is happening because your jquery selector is wrong. Add id to select tag and then select based on id. Learn more about selectors from https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: @MayurPatil actuallly drop down values are coming from database.also its difficult to change in sql query.

Comment: @jaspreet we have around 100 of drop downs in entire project. so  i am seeking for better choice instead of changing each SQL query for each dropdowns

Comment: This user means that     can  he sort all the   drop downs  in  multiple   html    pages or  single  page  using single j query  function(means  with out  specify class or id of particular  drop down)  without  help of Server side sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:-

```
   $(function() {
       // Loop for each select element on the page.
            $("select").each(function() {             
                // Keep track of the selected option.
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();     
                // Sort all the options by text. I could easily sort these by val.
                $(this).html($("option", $(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
                    if(a.text == "Choose a number") return 1;
                    if(b.text == "Choose a number") return 1;
                    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
                }));     
                // Select one option.
                $(this).val(selectedValue);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Just want to add that the sorting here I have written is case sensitive so capital 'Z' will be smaller than small 'a'

Comment: Thanks its working. But there is a problem, the selected(<option>choose a Number</option>) option also sorted. how to exclude that option. still i want that option in first

Comment: Everything is fixed, But the <option>choose a number</option> is not stay as selected when opening a form. it only appears when clicking on drop down menu